# macvlan-network device doesn't communicate outside host from within a container

Tags: docker, rhev, macvlan

I am attempting to erect a set of Docker or LXC containers, each with their own routable IP address. The containing host is actually a VM running within RedHat Enterprise Virtualization, which is a re-branded and very old version of oVirt. In our datacenter, we are using tagged VLANs, and within RHEV, these VLANs are selectable via different "LAN Profiles". I hope to put the containers all on the same VLAN/profile as the Host container. I hope to allow each container to have one virtual LAN device with its own MAC.

The containing VM has interface eth0. By following [this guide](http://blog.oddbit.com/2014/08/11/four-ways-to-connect-a-docker/) ("With macvalan devices"), I created a macvlan in bridge mode and assigned it to the container. For our purposes, we will say `10.12.0.117/21` is a routable address the container should have, and `10.12.7.254` is its gateway.

```
# docker run -d --name test centos7
# dockpid=$(docker inspect --format '{{ .State.Pid }}' test)
# ip link add eth0p0 link eth0 type macvlan mode bridge
# ip link set netns $dockpid eth0p0
# nsenter -t $dockpid -n ip link del eth0
# nsenter -t $dockpid -n ip addr add 10.12.0.117/21 dev eth0p0
# nsenter -t $dockpid -n ip route add default via 10.12.7.254 dev eth0p0
```

It's not pingable. In fact, using `tcpdump` on `eth0`, and `arping` from another node on the network, I can see the arp requests getting TO the container, and I can see the container responding (with its randomly-generated MAC), but those ARP responses don't seem to get back to the other host (as seen by TCP/IP).

I also tried with lxc, creating the interface in a simple fashion:

```
# ip link add link eth0 eth4 type macvlan
```

If I give it an IP address and UP the device, the IP becomes pingable on the LAN. But not when I configure the container:

```
lxc.network.type = phys
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = eth4
```

and then manually configuring the IP and routing. Now its unpingable as with docker.

If, by contrast, I use RHEV-M to create an additional network interface with the same profile, attach it to the VM, and then within the VM assign this new interface (`eth2`) to the container's namespace, everything works just fine. So I'm guessing this has something to do with RHEV and forwarding of ARP requests from the inside.

BTW: I don't have root on the RHEVM VM's hypervisor. (But I can ask politely if I can get it.)

Is there an obvious solution to this? Does anyone have troubleshooting tips? What am I missing?